# Array to object in other sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array:

```
let arr = ['0 abc', '81 abc', '63 abc', '108 abc', '100 abc', '80 abc', '54 abc', '128 abc', '32 abc', '9 abc'];
```

I want this final result:

```
{
 '0': '0 abc',
 '81': '81 abc',
 '63': '63 abc',
 '108': '108 abc',
 ...
}
```

So I do this function:

```
function arrayObj(arr){
    let obj = arr.reduce((prevVal, item) => {
        let sp = item.split(' ');
        let number = sp.splice(0,1);
    prevVal[number] = item;
    return prevVal;
}, {});

return obj;
```

But my function log this in other sequence of the original array:

```
{
      '0': '0 abc',
      '9': '9 abc',
      '32': '32 abc',
      '54': '54 abc',
      '63': '63 abc',
      '80': '80 abc',
      '81': '81 abc',
      '100': '100 abc',
      '108': '108 abc',
      '128': '128 abc'
    }
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Your answer looks correct. What is the problem?

Comment: the problem is the sequence of log, the righ: {
 '0': '0 abc',
 '81': '81 abc',

Comment: the wrong: {
      '0': '0 abc',
      '9': '9 abc',

Comment: 0, 9, 32 is wrong,

Comment: [JS does ordering of the object keys by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order#:~:text=The%20order%20is%20essentially%3A%20integer,order%2C%20Symbols%20in%20creation%20order.)

Comment: I want: 0,81,63

Comment: You can't dictate the order of keys in an object. Why does it matter anyway?

Comment: Basically, insertion order is not respected for numeric keys-- you can see the duplicate linked in the closure for more information.

Comment: understand, i just need it because its one exercise

Comment: but how i can do it?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to simply prepend the number with an underscore, and handle it on the way in and out.  Like `{ _0: '0 abc', _81: '81 abc' }`, etc.